# armeabi-v7a app works on ARM64 Nexus 5X

Tags: android, armv7, arm64

I have a mobile game.
I extracted that,
in `lib` directory there was only `armeabi-v7a` and `x86` folder.

I think `arm64-v8a` folder has to exist to successfully launch the app,
however, it doesn't exist, the game works fine.

In `adb shell`,
I typed that.

```
/data/data/that.game.package/lib/libFOO.so
```

It says Illegal instruction.

Also System.load-ing that library outside of that app causes an error like

`E/AndroidRuntime(): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: "/data/app/that.game.package-bar/lib/arm/libFOO.so" is 32-bit instead of 64-bit.`

So how does the game works?

Any other secret directories to contain arm64 libraries?

Comment: What makes you think that a 64-bit machine can't run 32-bit programs? As it happens, this comment is posted from a 32-bit web browser on a 64-bit OS...

Comment: If you're surprised by a 64-bit Android device running 32-bit binaries, then it will really surprise you to learn that ARM-only binaries (again on Android) can run on x86 devices due to Intel's dynamic binary translation technology.